# How to migrate Dense layers from Tensorflow 1 to Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How I could migrate this layer to tf2

```
observations = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, OBSERVATIONS_SIZE])

h = tf.layers.dense(
     observations,
     units=hidden_layer_size,
     activation=tf.nn.relu,
     kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
)
```

I Found that the placeholder now is 'Input' and I used the Dense layers for tf2

I tried with:

```
observations = tf.keras.Input(
    shape = [ None, OBSERVATIONS_SIZE ],
    dtype = tf.float32
)

h = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
     observations,
     units=hidden_layer_size,
     activation='relu',
     kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'
)
```

I get this error if i use it

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'units'
```

How i should use the placeholder/Input in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras layers are not used as `tf.layers`, they are callable instead of passing a tensor as the first parameter, so it should be:

```
observations = tf.keras.Input(
    shape = [ None, OBSERVATIONS_SIZE ],
    dtype = tf.float32
    )

h = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
     units=hidden_layer_size,
     activation='relu',
     kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'
     )(observations)
```